# calling function inside function with same class and redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am working on login and search functionality using `CodeIgniter`.

> What Exactly I am doing?

When the user searches something in the search form and on submitting that form I put a check if the user is logged in then it will directly show the result & if the user is not logged in then it redirects the user to the login page and I saved the search data in `session` as `search_session_data`.

I have a controller which redirects user regarding the session. If the user came directly to the login page then the user is redirected to the dashboard after login. but if the user is coming from search page then the user is redirected to the search result page after login.

I have mentioned the problem inside the code with a comment.

This is the controller:

```
public function get_the_search_result() {

        $search_session_data = $this->session->userdata('search_session_data');
        $this->load->model ('my_model');
        $result_data = $this->my_model->find_data_regarding_search_criteria($search_session_data);

        $this->load->view ('app/app_statch_result',['result_data' => $result_data,]);
}


public function login_function() {
    //necessary  login code

    if ($this->session->userdata('search_session_data')) {

        //Here I want the if `search_session_data` available in session then 
        // user goest to `get_the_search_result` and view the
         //'app/app_statch_result` but it is not working.

        $this->get_the_search_result();
    } else {
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }

}
```

> So How do I redirect the user to `app_statch_result` from
>   `login_function` function?

Any suggestion regarding improvement is applicable. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374759/redirect-to-referer-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: Sir @urfusion I am not redirecting the user only I mean user redirect with the search result data if it came from the search page.

Comment: @urfusion and sorry sir I have visited that question before asking but I can not get what they are trying to suggest.

Comment: Hey, I was trying to say that `reefer url ` redirect on the same page from which you came from.

Comment: ok. I had to read out that documentation first. thanks for the suggestion. can I ask if I had any query regarding this? @urfusion

Comment: sure, SO is open 24*7 :D

Comment: @urfusion Sir, sorry but your suggested link is not gone help me to solve this problem, I read it and what I understand that it is about `whether the user agent browsing your site is a web browser, a mobile device, or a robot.`

Comment: @always-a-learner What is ['result_data' => $result_data,] ? Why is there a comma in there? Why not just "app/app_statch_result', $result_data"? What output are you getting in your view? You're also convoluting things by loading your search functionality directly from your login method instead of redirecting to a separate controller. It looks like a lot of this is redacted, also. I understand wanting to hide sensitive parts of your code, but in this case it's just hindering your getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do the following:

1. Create login controller, or better, library and put all login logic inside that class. Then you can load that library from any controller... For example:

Sample library

```
    class User_controll{
        private $CI;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->CI = &get_instance();
        }

        public function check_user_data($username, $password) {
            $tmpId;
            // To increase security you can encrypt password
            $user = $this->CI->db->from('users')->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password))->get()->result();

            if(count($user) == 1){
                $this->CI->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 1);
                redirect('user_page');
            }
        }
        protected function logout() {
            $this->CI->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 0);
        }

        public function isLoggedIn() {
            return $this->CI->session->userdata('loggedIn') == 1;
        }

    }
```

Sample Controller

```
    class User_page extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('User_controll');
        }
        public function index() {
            if(!$this->user_controll->isLoggedIn()){
                redirect('user_page/loginForm');
            }
            else {
                // do whatever you want
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this not what I am looking for sir.